# In Visual Studio 2019, how can I remove the formatting of white space between () and { in a function declaration? C#

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, ide

There appears to be no option for automatic formatting, it slightly irritates me. Perhaps I have OCD:

private void someFunc() {

}

// I want

private void someFunc(){

}

I have tried looking in |options > text editor > C# > code style > formatting| ... to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In c# formatting is no entirely automatic. You need to press `ctrl+k;ctrl+e` to format file.

> For C# code files, Visual Studio 2019 has a Code Cleanup button at the bottom of the editor (keyboard: Ctrl+K, Ctrl+E) to apply code styles from an EditorConfig file or from the Code Style options page.

Use instruction from here [to setup your style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2019)

But, if there is a space or no space - you must set in your style setting.